# Tensors transpose

Tags: tensors

I was wondering about the following orthogonality relationship:

$A_{i,k}A_{j,k}=A_{k,i}A_{k,j}=\delta_{i,j}$ its matrix equivalent is
$AA^{T}=A^{T}A=\delta_{i,j}$

My question:

In the first/second terms I am multiplying a tensor $A_{i,k}$ by its transpose. If i am using the transpose of $A_{i,k}$ why not multiply by $A_{k,i}$ (As far I can see this is the transpose) instead of $A_{j,k}$?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, $A_{ik}A_{ki}$ is a scalar - if you repeat both indices, then both indices get summed over, and there are no "free" indices left! That's two fewer than you need to end up with to have a matrix. Consider how to separately represent transpose and matrix multiplication itself with tensors.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question well, the reason that $A_{i,k}A_{j,k}$ in tensor multiplication convention is equivalent to $AA^T$, is that $A\cdot A$ itself is equivalent to
$$
A\cdot A=A^2=A_{i,k}A_{k,j}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}A_{i,k}A_{k,j},
$$
where the latter equality shows the equivalence between tensor product notation and matrix product notation. Hence it must be that $AA^T$ comes from $A\cdot A$ by reordering the indices of $A_{k,j}$, that is
$$
AA^T=A_{i,k}A_{j,k}.
$$
Same thing holds for the other equality.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you!!

Comment: Happy to help :)